# Display a list of all PDF files on HDD in a Cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, pdf, xcode4.2

I am trying to make a simple OS x PDF reader in Xcode 4.2. I would like to have a drawer that displays all the PDF files on the users computer with the ability to click on a select PDF and have my PDFView display it. I currently have everything set up, I have my main window and drawer with a Browser View as its content view. How can I populate the Browser View with a list of all PDF files on the HDD and have the list selectable to open that PDF file? This is where i am stuck and am tired of searching so I broke down and decided to ask for help. I am fairly new to Objective-C and am using Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard 10.6.8. Any help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`NSFileManager` contains methods to enumerate the items in a directory tree, e.g. see `enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:`. Using such an enumerator you check each found item against your criteria, in this case being a PDF, and process the ones which match.

If you'd like a lower-level way of doing this look at `fts(3)` in the manual pages.